# Chatter post with attachment not visible on record page ( Case Object)

Tags: chatter, attachment, chatter-feed, post

On the Case object, when i try to post a message with attachment (with the Chatter feed component), the message doesnt appear but it's visible in the lightning page builder of the record (there are no filters on components too)

it works on other object than Case like account and i don't understand why

[image]

On the record

[image]

On the lightning builder app

Thanks for your attention

Comment: I tried this in my org with Case object and the attachment is visible in the same way as it appears in the lightning page builder. Can you try this in a different org and confirm if you are seeing the same behavior? Thanks